# Get uptime for multiple VM's

Tags: linux, command-line, vmware, uptime

Is it possible to get the uptime for other VM's that are on the same cluster without the need to ssh?

Comment: Do you want the uptime of the OS in the VM, or the uptime of the VM?

Comment: What's the hypervisor and virtualisation solution?

Comment: I want the uptime for the VM and I use VMware